# Can I download a new program to a Silicon Labs C8051F311 with a JTAG programmer?

Tags: 8051, programmer, flash

Or does that chip require a bunch of weird voltages that can only be generated by a "special" expensive device programmer?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this community wiki?

Comment: I understand what "wiki" means on other web sites -- it means other people can fix-up my all too frequent typos, making me look smart.
The chiphacker FAQ implies it means the same thing here.
If it means something different on Stack Exchange web sites, could you give me a link to the explanation?

Comment: Here, wiki means that nobody gets any points. It's used for questions that might have multiple correct answers or provoke discussion. This question probably shouldn't be a wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Section 20 of the [datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F31x.pdf)

> C8051F31x devices include an on-chip
>   Silicon Labs 2-Wire (C2) debug
>   interface to allow Flash program- ming
>   and in-system debugging with the
>   production part installed in the end
>   application. The C2 interface uses a
>   clock signal (C2CK) and a
>   bi-directional C2 data signal (C2D) to
>   transfer information between the
>   device and a host system. See the C2
>   Interface Specification for details on
>   the C2 protocol.

So, yes, sounds like you need a special (non JTAG) programmer.

[Here's one](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBDebug.aspx), it's $35.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to know, and I like the way you pre-emptively answered what would have been my next question.

Comment: 35$ is too much.

Comment: @sandundhammika Then build your own from a cheap microcontroller or IO interface on a PC. The protocol seems to be documented.